# Clear SPN changes from server cache

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, iis-7.5, spn

We have in house IIS apps built on ASP .Net 2.0 running on IIS 7.5- Server 2008 R2 x64. Back end is SQL 2005. It uses Kerberos (Windows integrated) authentication. Once in a while we need to change SPNs that map the site name to the server, when a new server is put into production or a site is moved to a different server.

Most recent change required me to reboot the IIS & SQL servers for the SPN change to take effect. Before reboot, users get authentication errors in IE.

Is there a less intrusive way to get the SPN changes to take effect? These are 24/7 production sites, so service restarts and/or server reboots are difficult.

Comment: Have you tried setspn -D?

Comment: Yes, that's part of the change process. I use setspn -D to remove the old one, then setspn -S to add the new record (-S checks for duplicates). However these changes don't take effect for clients, not even days later. Rebooting fixed it. It seems that the records are cached in IIS/SQL or both, because if I make a new DNS test record for the same site, add a brand new SPN, add host header values to the site, it all works right away. Changing existing records and moving the site to a different server causes the headaches.

Comment: To clarify, Rebooting the IIS & SQL servers fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use klist on each of your server instances to clear the cached tickets:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134826.aspx

My problem is with cached tickets on the client side, which can also cause problems.

[Adding new SPNs to existing service ids](https://serverfault.com/questions/549898/adding-new-spns-to-existing-service-ids)